# How do I fix my code so that when the button is pressed it will only increment the vote count of the corresponding post?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I know that the value of the button is what chooses the id but when I try to switch it to a variable it doesn't work, because of this the button will only increment the 1st post in my db when clicked. My goal is to get it to increments the vote_count of its corresponding post. Please note that posts are randomly selected. Here is my code.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'phplikes');
    $sql = "SELECT vote from meme_vote";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $vote  = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        $sql1 = "UPDATE meme_vote set vote = (vote + 1) where id =  ". $_POST['id'];
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql1);
        $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $vote = $result2->fetch_assoc();
        echo json_encode($vote);die();
    }
    
    
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'phplikes');
    $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT video_location FROM meme_vote
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1");
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)){
           $location = $row['video_location'];
   
       echo "<div >";
       echo "<video src='".$location."' controls width='200px' height='200px' >";
       echo "</div>";
     
 
         echo "<div class='meme'>";
echo "<button type='button' id='press_me' value='1'>waat</button>";    
 echo '<p>Post 2<div id="votes">'.$vote['vote'].'</div>'; 
    echo "</div>";
 }
     
?>

<html>
<style>
    #votess {
        position: relative; top: 230px ; left: 50px;
    }
    #testvid {
        position: relative; bottom: 230px ; left: 300px;
    }
    
    }
    </style>
</html>
           
           
  
<?php

?>

<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</html>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#press_me').click(function() {
            var postid = $(this).val();
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "memeVote.php",
                data: {
                    'id': postid
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#votes").text(obj.vote);
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi ,what doesn't work currently ? Are you getting any error ? Check your browser console .

Comment: its only updating the vote count of the post with id 1

Comment: I want to make it so that it will update the vote count of its corresponding post as it is selecting posts randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your **button** like below so that it will pass `id` of corresponding post only i.e :

```
echo "<button type='button' data-value ='".$row['id']."' class='press_me' value='1'>waat</button>";
```

Now , `data-value` will have value of particular `id` of posts and also change your `id` to `class`. Then , your **jquery** code will look like below :

```
//change id to class
$('.press_me').click(function() {
  var postid = $(this).attr('data-value');//get attr value
  //your ajax call
});
```

Comment: I did that but it now says "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Meme Swipe\memeVote.php on line 26"

Comment: Hi , you are printing your post like above only na with button ? Also can you do `alert(postid)` and see if that gets show and give correct values ?

Comment: Hi ,does above works for your ? You can upvote and accept it :)